# Yii2 Rest api call multiple methods

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I am using this piece of code, and try using REST API in yii2.
I tried to use two function as you seen in the code snippet.

1. getAllData
2. getSpecificData

   ```
   <?php

   namespace app\api\modules\widgetmodule\controllers;

   use yii\rest\Controller;

   class WidgetController extends Controller
   {
   public $modelClass = 'app\models\DynamicWidget';

   public function actions()
   {
       return [
           'index' => [
               'class' => 'yii\rest\IndexAction',
               'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
               'prepareDataProvider' => [$this, 'getAllData']
           ],
           'view' => [
               'class' => 'yii\rest\ViewAction',
               'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
               'prepareDataProvider' => [$this, 'getSpecificData']
           ],
       ];
   }

   public function getAllData()
   {
       die('get all data');
   }

   public function getSpecificData()
   {
       die('get specific data');
   }
   }
   ```

I tried two URLs for the two different methods,

http://localhost/api/web/widgetmodule/widget/getAllData

http://localhost/api/web/widgetmodule/widget/getSpecificData

But the output will always be like.

Quote
get all data

Here is my URL manager code in api.php

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => ['widgetmodule/widget']
                ]
            ],
        ], 
        'db' => $db,
    ],
    'modules' => [
        'widgetmodule' => [
           'class' => 'app\api\modules\widgetmodule\Module',
        ],
```

So could anyone help me, how to get different outputs with two different methods.

It is anyways calling the first method.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you forget the word of action in create method in your controller .

Comment: instead this `public function getAllData()`  use this `public function actionGetAllData()`  and url will be `http://localhost/api/web/widgetmodule/widget/get-all-data`   because you use camel case

Answer (score 0):

1- The only 2 actions you did define inside your controller are `index` and `view` and because index is rendering `getAllData` it is why you are getting that output.

2- the `view` action has no `prepareDataProvider` attribute.

maybe you meant something like this instead:

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'index' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\IndexAction',
            'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
            'prepareDataProvider' => [$this, 'getAllData']
        ],
        'view' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\ViewAction',
            'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
        ],
    ];
}

public function getAllData()
{
    // return some dataProvider instance to be used by index
    $modelClass = $this->modelClass;

    return new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $modelClass::find(),
    ]);
}
```

And that is defining two actions: `index` and `view` where index's dataProvider is overriden by a custom function `getAllData()`. that requires something similar to those configs:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
    'controller' => ['widgetmodule/widget'], 
    'patterns' => [
        'GET,HEAD index'  => 'index',
        'GET,HEAD view/{id}' => 'view',
    ]
],
```

So you can access them within the following endpoints:

```
http://localhost/api/web/widgetmodule/widget/index
http://localhost/api/web/widgetmodule/widget/view/4
```

Now if your question is how to add an extra action to that in order to respond to the uri `http://localhost/api/web/widgetmodule/widget/getSpecificData` then you'll need to add this to your patterns:

```
'patterns' => [
    ...
    ...
    'GET getSpecificData'  => 'some-specific-data',
]
```

and define that action inside your controller as described in official docs by simply adding this:

```
public function actionSomeSpecificData()
{
    return 'some specific data';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Salem, I have changed all patterns, for custom function and for the view action override. But still I am getting same output for all requests. **'get all data'**. Is there any more changes required for the same.

Answer (score 0):

First unset default index and view actions, like this:

```
public function actions()
{
    $actions = parent::actions();
    // unset default index action for custom our own code
    unset($actions['index']);
    unset($actions['view']);

    return ArrayHelper::merge($actions, [
        'index' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\IndexAction',
            'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
            'prepareDataProvider' => [$this, 'getAllData']
        ],
        'view' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\ViewAction',
            'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
            'prepareDataProvider' => [$this, 'getSpecificData']
        ],
    ];
}
```

Config routes like this:

```
[
  'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
  'controller' => ['widgetmodule/widget'], 
  'patterns' => [
    'GET,HEAD index'  => 'index',
    'GET,HEAD view/{id}' => 'view',
 ]
],
```

Then you can call these urls:

```
http://localhost/api/web/widgetmodule/widget/index
http://localhost/api/web/widgetmodule/widget/view/4
```